# Placing contents inside an iframe (breaks in ie)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to place generated variable strings inside an iframe in design mode (richTextEditor). It works beautifully in all browsers except... you guessed it IE. IE won't process the string variable inside the iframe at all. Here is what I have...

Html (pretty basic)

```
<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" class="writer"></iframe>
```

PHP (again very basic) - Disclaimer... mysql_query is not a good practice, will change to PDO later. This is for testing purposes only!

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1") or die();
    while($song=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $title = $song['title'];
        $base_text = $song['song_chart'];
          $base_text = str_replace('<br />', '<br>', $base_text);
    }
```

Here is the problem Javascript...

```
window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML = '<?php echo $base_text; ?>';
//I have also tried...
$('iframe').contents().find('body').html('<?php echo $base_text; ?>');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I am doing this completely wrong can someone help me with a new direction. Thank You

**EDIT**

Tested in IE7, IE8, IE9, non functioning in any of them

Comment: Sorry i'll edit... tested in ie7, ie8, and ie9. non functioning in all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this javascript code

```
window.frames['richTextField'].document.write('<?php echo $base_text; ?>');
window.frames['richTextField'].document.designMode="on";
```

Comment: Still doesn't work in IE, also by placing src in the iframe it takes pulls the iframe out of design mode. Good idea about the doc domain though!

Comment: Try replacing your initializing javascript with the code above.

Comment: Perfect Thank you so much! The last two lines of code worked like a dream.

Comment: Was looking for the Fuctionality @JuanGonzales Was questioning about! Thank you so much, and I don't now have to worry about IE Compatibility either. What A perfect day! :)

Comment: Also note that you should do `echo json_encode($base_text);` instead.